# upgrading project to Angular 8

Tags: rxjs, angular8

I've followed the instruction from https://update.angular.io/#7.2:8.0l3 and deleted the rxjs-compat from my project. From now I have this error during ng serve:

```
../node_modules/rxjs/Rx.d.ts:1:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat'.

 export * from 'rxjs-compat';
```

also I have

```
Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>'.

             .catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
```

What should I do to fix this? I have "primeng": "9.1.2",
"rxjs": "6.6.0" in my package.json

Comment: try to delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and then `npm install`

Comment: still the same error. I've got property catch, map, of does not exist on Observable

Comment: toget rid of error with map I've added .pipe(map(...)) ant it's ok but it doesnt work for of and catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello mario the reason is quite simple, there is no more `catch` operator in `rxjs` the new one is called `catchError` if you go in the rxjs changelog [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)
and scroll to 5.5.0 beta you will see the introduction of the new pipebale operators where the `catchError` is introduced as the successor of `catch`, where `catch` was later on removed/deprecated (version 6-7). The case is the same for the `do` and `tap` operator.

The thing that I will suggest is to go here at [rxjs docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/v6/migration) and read the full migration guide, it is very helpful.